# How can I get cscope results to appear in a split window in gvim7?

Tags: vim, cscope

I have tried the tutorial here: [Vim/Cscope tutorial](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/cscope_vim_tutorial.html).  After changing the `@`'s in the `cscope_maps.vim` file to `SPACE` I got `Ctrl-SPACE s` to launch cscope in gVim.  However, it takes over the whole window rather than splitting the window for the cscope info.

I then tried as suggested in the comments to the `cscope_maps.vim` file changing `nmap <C-SPACE>s :scs find s <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>` to `nmap <C-SPACE>s <C-W><C-S> :cs find s <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>` because it appears that my gVim does nto support the `:scs` command.  However, this still displays the cscope info in a full window, blocking out my code.  When I exit the cscope interface, I return to two split screens.

Any help on how to craft a command in gVim 7.3 that will launch cscope in a split window?

Comment: What `:version` of Vim do you use? `:scscope` has been around for a while.

Comment: @romainl VIM 7.3, MS-Windows 32-bit (is Windows my problem?).  My `:scscope` command seems to just invoke `:cscope`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`scscope find c foo` does what it's supposed to do: display a list of functions calling `foo` in the command line and open the chosen one in an horizontal split.

But that is not what you want, is it?

The list of possible targets is *always* displayed in the command line which is expanded as needed: it can't be displayed in a window at all.

[image: cscope in action (default)]

That said, you can use the quickfix window to display the list instead of the command line, see `:help cscope-options`.

[image: cscope in action (quickfix)]